# Javascript sum dynamic django rest framework entries

Tags: javascript

I'm working on an app that allows a user to calculate information regarding a trade based on their entries. I've been stuck getting proper calculations on trade sums based on entries being added after the page has already retrieved any existing entries.

```
<td scope="col">${sumTotal('amount')}</td>
```

```
<script>
    ...
        mounted() {
            this.trade_id = window.location.pathname.split("/")[3];
            // Get entries of trade
            axios
                .get('/trade/' + window.location.pathname.split("/")[3] + '/entries/')
                .then(response => (this.entries = response.data));
        },
    ...
        methods: {
            sumTotal(base) {
                return Math.round(this.entries.reduce((sum, cur) => sum + cur[base], 0));
            }
</script>
```

When the page first loads and pulls the existing entries the first calculation (first column) is correct with 16. However, when I add a new entry the auto-calculated value is no longer true.

[image]

The first column should be 26 but now is 1610

[image]

---

I can add much more info as needed. I wasn't sure how much would be required and I didn't want to clutter the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened on JS side,

it is because you are adding a numeric value with a string value, the result will be the concatenation of both values in a new string.

if you noticed

previous sum was `16`, and the new value is `10`
their concatenation will be `1610`

the solution is as simple as converting the new value from string to a numeric value

You should change the line inside `sumTotal` to:

```
return Math.round(this.entries.reduce((sum, cur) => sum + parseInt(cur[base]), 0));
```

Comment: ahhh, this now seems a bit ridiculous. I knew I was concatenating but I just didn't know how I was doing it. Think I was just looking at it for way to long. Thanks Radwan!! Killer help.